# Capturing sleep/hibernate/wakeup events on Linux desktop and laptop environments

Tags: suspend, power-management, hibernate, acpi, dbus

Explored 2 options to capture these power events, but unfortunately none of them worked as expected.

1. DBus works on Desktop but these events also need to be captured on Laptops and Linux environments without any GUI. Is there a way to use DBus in both such situations?
2. Acpid  requires us to write scripts and put these scripts in specific paths and in turn these scripts call the required running application. In the opensource implementation,  the latest version uses netlink sockets to catch the signal. Tried to capture the events using netlink which worked when running on the VM but unfortunately, did not work on Linux physical machine.

Is there any other way to capture these events?

Comment: Any GUI application you are using to monitor DBus is purely optional for your own convenience. DBus works on all Ubuntu systems, and it can be monitored headlessly. For an example, see the `dbus-monitor` shell application.

Comment: This is a Ubuntu (and *flavor*) site; if you want Linux support, I'd suggest SE *Unix and Linux*, why are you asking here?  Please provide OS & release details (some options vary on the software stack and you've provided no specifics)  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thank you, ill post it on the other site. Tried to capture events using netlink sockets on Ubuntu 20.04 physical desktop machine which did not work. The same worked on Ubuntu 20.04 running on Oracle VM for sleep and wakeup events.